# Config route in seperate file and consume in app.module.ts , HTML and component.ts file angular 5/6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-routing, angular6

I want to separate the appRoutes to the separate .ts file and import in it app.module.ts to consume the value in the RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes).

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin-portal' ,component: AdminMainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent },
      { path: 'user', component: AdminUserComponent },
      { path: 'role', component: AdminRoleComponent },
      { path: 'rule', component: AdminRuleComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'counter',
    component: CounterComponent,
    pathMath: 'full'
  },
  {
    path:  'fetch-data',
    component: FetchDataComponent,
    pathMath: 'full'
  },
  {
    path:  'login',
    component: AuthComponent,
    pathMath: 'full'
  }
];
```

Now in the import section I have value for RouterModule

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
```

Instead of putting in the app.module.ts file how can I seperate the router component to seperate file and consume in app.module.ts , HTML, component.ts file.

Trying some of the suggestion link about dynamic routing from the below link  : -

https://myview.rahulnivi.net/dynamically-importing-modules-related-components-angular-45/

https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create custom router module.

**appRoutingModule.ts**

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin-portal' ,component: AdminMainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent },
      { path: 'user', component: AdminUserComponent },
      { path: 'role', component: AdminRoleComponent },
      { path: 'rule', component: AdminRuleComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'counter',
    component: CounterComponent,
    pathMath: 'full'
  },
  {
    path:  'fetch-data',
    component: FetchDataComponent,
    pathMath: 'full'
  },
  {
    path:  'login',
    component: AuthComponent,
    pathMath: 'full'
  }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

import the module in main app module

**appModule.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule, // router
    BrowserAnimationsModule
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dedicated routing module: `app-routing.module.ts`.

This is manage automatically with the angular-cli when you generate a new project with the option --routing : `ng new myproject --routing`. It will generate a separate routing module with your app-module with the necessary imports. This option can be used when generating a module with the cli: `ng generate module mymodule --routing`.

Here is the generated module code :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

You just have then to import `AppRoutingModule` in your `AppModule`.